# Out of range error for Windows().Activate

Tags: excel, vba

I have a bit of code in my macro as follows

```
ChDir File_pth
Workbooks.Open filename:= File_pth & "\" & open_tkt
Workbooks.Open filename:= File_pth & "\" & closed_tkt
ActiveSheet.Select
Windows("MSS - Ticket Backlog Benchmark_2013 09 05.xlsx").Activate
Sheets("Extract -prev").Select
```

When I run the macro to open two other files, it should go back to the file in which I run macro to do some operations in the same Xl workbook.

I get the out of range error in the line

```
Windows("MSS - Ticket Backlog Benchmark_2013 09 05.xlsx").Activate
```

The file MSS - Ticket Backlog Benchmark_2013 09 05.xlsx exists.

Comment: Have you thought about setting references to your open workbooks instead of using Windows("...")? Search SO youll find plenty of questions with good answers

Comment: hi as i am new to VB i know very less, all i have done was recording some action as anew macro and used the vb script produced by that new macro, could you please explain what is setting references to a work book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

`windows("MSS - Ticket Backlog Benchmark_2013 09 05").Activate`

you could check the names of all open workbooks in Debug window like this:

```
dim oBook as workbook

for each obook in workbooks
    debug.print ">" & obook.name & "<"
next
```

Comment: so this name **("MSS - Ticket Backlog Benchmark_2013 09 05.xlsx"** is wrong. try checking the names of open workbooks in the Debug window.

Comment: the name of the file is correct i've used this same line to switch between open workbooks but now it is not working, previously i have manually opend all the workbook tha i need to work on , now i have wrote the code (collected from net)                 
         ChDir _
        File_pth
    Workbooks.Open filename:= _
        File_pth & "\" & open_tkt 'opening the open ticket file
    Workbooks.Open filename:= _
        File_pth & "\" & closed_tkt  'opening the closed ticket file      
   to open the other files through macro itself

Comment: aha! Methinks here is a version issue, what version of Excel are you using? Is it an **xls** file or an **xlxs** file? Was it saved in compatibility mode with Excel 2003?

Comment: i have found the problem the file is actually xlsx format only , even when i do the record a macro it gives the file name with extention .xlsx thanks to your debug code which shows that the file has an extention of .xlsm. i don't know why it is changing...... do you have any idea of why it is changing ???? or is there any option to pass the name of file without extention and it selects any file type with the exact name match???

Comment: I have edited my answer to avoid using the extension, if it works, please **accept it**

Comment: it changes to **xlsm** file because there are macros or macro code in the file when it is saved.

Comment: could you please help me in how to check the document is first available in the specified path????

Comment: @murugan_kotheesan - you can do that with the VBA **Dir** function. See [MSDN Library: VBA Dir Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278779.aspx) and [Walkenbach's Spreadsheet Page Excel VBA Tips: Dir Funtion](http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/site/tip/identifying_the_newest_file_in_a_directory/) and [ExcelTrick - Dire Function](http://www.exceltrick.com/formulas_macros/vba-dir-function/)

Comment: @murugan_kotheesan you can also see more on this at: [Ron de Bruin Excel MVP: Scripting Runtime and FSO](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win003.htm) and [Ozgrid Excel MVP](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/DoesExcelWorkbookExist.htm) and [Chip Pearson Excel MVP](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/Topic.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Activating the original sheet should bring the original window to the front too, so you shouldn't need to play with the windows. (works for me anyway)

```
Dim Book As Workbook ' probably not needed
Set Book = ThisWorkbook ' probably not needed
Dim Sheet As Worksheet
Set Sheet = ActiveSheet
ChDir File_pth
Workbooks.Open filename:= File_pth & "\" & open_tkt
Workbooks.Open filename:= File_pth & "\" & closed_tkt
Book.Activate() ' probably not needed
Sheet.Activate()
```

I've added code to activate the original workbook before activating the original sheet (lines with the comments at the end) and as it says, they are probably not needed.

The variables `Book` and `Sheet` are references to The active workbook (ThisWorkbook) and the active sheet (ActiveSheet). This is what @mehow was suggesting.

Answer (score 0):

You must place your macros in modules instead of in "This Workbook" or in specific sheets. Otherwise, you will have that window interaction problem. I had the very same issue and that's how I solved it.

Like this:

[image]