# Windows().Activate works on every computer except one

Tags: vba, excel, debugging

I have encountered a strange problem, I made macro about a **year ago** and it is being used **every month without problems**. Yesterday my boss told me, he cannot use it anymore, that it gives him some errors. I now tried the macro on **8 computers** and the macro **ran perfectly**. Why is it that macro runs on everyone else's computer, except for my boss.

The line it breaks on

```
Windows("MyxlsbFile").Activate
```

And the error given is

> Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range.

Comment: Based on this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16540071/out-of-range-error-for-windows-activate) I would double check what version of Excel he is running and what file format the workbook is saved in.

Comment: you're missing the extension ".xlsb" by the looks of the post.

Comment: The file is on shared disk, so there should not be format/extension problem, also the version of excel is same for our whole department. Sadly I can update tomorrow with the provided debug, because he now left.

Comment: Do you have a reference to the Workbook in a variable already?

Comment: No, I don't @Comintern

Comment: You might need to post more of the code then.  If you can get a reference to the Workbook, it's as easy as doing this: `Application.Windows(wb.Name).Activate`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Whether or not you can leave off the file extension when calling (eg)

```
Windows("MyxlsbFile")
```

or

```
Workbooks("MyxlsbFile")
```

depends on whether the Windows Explorer setting "hide extensions for known file types" has been checked or not: if file extensions are shown in Windows Explorer then you must include the extension when calling `WorkBooks()`.

I'm guessing this is the issue on the one PC where you have the problem.

Including the file extension always works, regardless of the Explorer setting (as long as there's no other error of course) so that's the safest approach to take.

Comment: This was the thing ! I needed to add Windows("MyxlsbFile.xlsb") . Thank you very much