# Excel xlsm file runs on my machine, but won't run properly on others

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013, sharing

This is not a Trust-Center related issue as far as I can tell. I've compared my machine's Trust-Center to another co-workers and they are exactly the same.

Some of the code clearly runs, as it will give usual warnings for empty combo-boxes etc. However when the code runs, it doesn't seem to read from one of the sheets containing data. The only thing I've found that's different on my machine is PTrendXL instead (I have no idea where this comes from).

This is quite baffling, if anyone has any insight into why my co-workers can't run this it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to show some *speciifc* problem and the related code.  Without knowing exactly what your code does it's difficult to suggest what might be the problem.  Here's one possibility (but just guessing at this point): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38745818/windows-activate-works-on-every-computer-except-one/38748754#38748754

Comment: You could try use the relative approach instead of absolute. With recording macros there's an option for relative or absolute, and what this means basically is, when you have... Relative references, when you start the recording, if cell A1 is selected when the recording starts, when you run the macro, if you're on cell A3, it will apply everything in your code 2 lines down, as when you started the recording, the beginning point was A1, and now it's A3...

This may be happening with your current situation? Maybe the workbooks are not identical in data structure?