# VBA moving excel sheet to another workbook with unknown extension

Tags: vba, excel

```
Worksheets("Hello").Move After:=Workbooks("FILE2").Sheets(1)
```

I have two open active files. Hello.xlsb and FILE2.xlsb

The above code only works on my computer but not on shared drive.
I am getting "Subscript out of range error".

We need to specify the extension FILE2.xlsb to make it work.

However, I want this to work on any FILE2 with any extension.
How to make that work?

Comment: I take it you mean any new Excel file?  I can't see it working with an EXE extension.  Is NEW FILE an actual newly created file that hasn't been saved yet, or do you create a file and call it NEW FILE?

Comment: It is a generic existing Excel file. Also, why am I getting downvoted? I worked on this for a while and was not able to find a solution

Comment: when I say any extension I meant .xlsm .xlsb basically all flavors of excel spreadsheets.

Comment: Thought so....  got to be precise with coders though. :)

Answer (score 0):

This code will ask you to open the destination workbook and move the sheet into it, is it what you're after?

```
Public Sub Test()

    Dim vfile As Variant
    Dim wrkBk As Workbook

    'Ask for the location of File2.
    vfile = GetFile(ThisWorkbook.Path)

    Set wrkBk = Workbooks.Open(vfile)

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Hello").Move After:=wrkBk.Worksheets(1)

End Sub


Function GetFile(Optional startFolder As Variant = -1) As Variant
    Dim fle As FileDialog
    Dim vItem As Variant
    Set fle = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    With fle
        .Title = "Select a File"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Filters.Add "Excel Files", "*.xls*", 1
        If startFolder = -1 Then
            .InitialFileName = Application.DefaultFilePath
        Else
            If Right(startFolder, 1) <> "\" Then
                .InitialFileName = startFolder & "\"
            Else
                .InitialFileName = startFolder
            End If
        End If
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
        vItem = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With
NextCode:
    GetFile = vItem
    Set fle = Nothing
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

If your destination workbook is already open, then you can use this to safely refer to a workbook regardless of extension:

```
Function GetWb(wbName As String)
    Dim wb As Workbook, rv As Workbook
    For Each wb In Application.Workbooks
        If UCase(wb.Name) Like UCase(wbName & ".*") Then
            Set rv = wb
            Exit For
        End If
    Next wb
    Set GetWb = rv
End Function
```

Usage

```
Dim destWb As Workbook

Set destWb = GetWb("file2")
if destWb Is Nothing then
    Msgbox "destination file not open!"
else
    'perform the copy
end if
```

FYI this may be why you see differences between computers:

[Windows().Activate works on every computer except one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38745818/windows-activate-works-on-every-computer-except-one/38748754#38748754)