# VBA functions work, except on some computers where a runtime error 9 is produced

Tags: vba, excel

I am at work creating an excel document with multiple functions that execute upon open, close or throughout the spreadsheet.  I have tested the document on ~15 computers and on 12 of them the code works fine.  On the three computers that the code does not work on, a run-time error 9 is produced at the first executable line (after the sub definition and Dim) on every function.

Because it would be a waste of time for you to analyze the code, I am only posting the open and close functions.  To see if anyone notices some common problems (the run-time error is given EVERY time one of the three computers opens or closes the file).

I have two of the same files, one is an .xlsm the other is a .xls BOTH give the same error code on the same computers.

The following VBA code is in the ThisWorkbook section

```
'Open to first page, clear values, select "Part Number" in dropdown
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Dim ThisWS As Worksheet
Dim ThisWB As Workbook

Set ThisWB = Workbooks("CombinationIndex")
Set ThisWS = ThisWB.Worksheets("Index Search") 'selects the ws titled Index Search

ThisWS.Activate

'Sets the dropdown value to 'Part Number'
ThisWS.DropDowns("Drop Down 36").Value = 1

'Clears everything
ThisWS.Cells(1, 26).ClearContents

ThisWS.Columns("C:C").ClearContents
ThisWS.Range("B10:F250").ClearContents
ThisWS.Range("B10:F250").ClearFormats
'colors lines white
ThisWS.Range("B10:F250").Borders.Color = ThisWorkbook.Colors(2)

End Sub
```

---

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

Workbooks("CombinationIndex").Close SaveChanges:=False

End Sub
```

As far as I can tell, none of my code is whacky and everyone is on the same version (2010). Then when I click 'Debug' on the error option, it will direct me to the origin of the error which is at the first executable line.

For the Workbook_Open sub, code errors on:

```
Set ThisWB = Workbooks("CombinationIndex")
```

For the Workbook_BeforeClose sub, code errors on:

```
Workbooks("CombinationIndex").Close SaveChanges:=False
```

Any Ideas? This is very strange to me...

Comment: Try `Set ThisWB = Workbooks("CombinationIndex.xlsm")`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38745818/windows-activate-works-on-every-computer-except-one/38748754#38748754

Comment: I didn't know that had to with the settings.

Comment: Related: [Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vba/8917/vba-run-time-errors/27748/run-time-error-9-subscript-out-of-range#t=201702032011446433311)

Comment: The error message tells you exactly what the problem is, and you've shown two lines that have exactly one thing in common, which is `Workbooks("CombinationIndex")`. Index out of range means you're accessing something in a list/collection of things that doesn't exist (the index is out of the range allowed for the list/collection). So clearly "CombinationIndex" doesn't exist in the collection of Workbooks. It's really important to learn to *read the words* in error messages; they almost always contain information that will tell you what's wrong.

Comment: Thank you for your positive words of advice @KenWhite *'eyes roll'*
The good news is, you are partially right.
SOLUTION: Workbooks("CombinationIndex.xlsx")
Thank you all for referencing me to the other cites to help with the problem.