# Simple VBA macro will work on all computers except one

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote a program and it has worked on all computers in my workplace except one. The program errors out on a line like:

```
MsgBox Workbooks(WB).Sheets(IO).Range("A1").Value
```

I'm getting a

> run-time error 9 - subscript out of range.

The same file has been used on multiple computers and it's only one that is causing errors.

Has anyone had any experience with this? Could it be the settings of Excel on that computer that are causing this error?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204243/discussion-on-question-by-grace1997-simple-vba-macro-will-work-on-all-computers).

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> MsgBox Workbooks(WB).Sheets(IO).Range("A1").Value
> ```

This instruction has too many reasons to fail, it's impossible to tell where the error is coming from like this.

Split it up.

First get the workbook:

```
Dim book As Workbook
Set book = Application.Workbooks(WB)
```

Did that blow up? If so, then `WB` (presumably some `String` variable holding some workbook's file name?) is holding a value that does not exist in the `Workbooks` collection, and the bug is elsewhere.

If the macro is opening that workbook, then `WB` should be the `Workbook` object, and there should be no reason to dereference it from any `Workbooks` collection:

```
Dim WB As Workbook
Set WB = Application.Workbooks.Open(filename)
```

And now you have the `Workbook` object to work with.

If the macro isn't opening that workbook (e.g. macro runs and the file is already opened, and that isn't the same workbook as the file that contains your VBA project - that would be `ThisWorkbook`), then you need the *exact* collection key to retrieve the workbook: anything else will throw error 9.

*Next* you get the worksheet:

```
Dim sheet As Worksheet
Set sheet = WB.Worksheets(IO)
```

Or if `WB` is actually a `String` representing a workbook's name:

```
Dim book As Workbook
Set book = Application.Workbooks(WB)

Dim sheet As Worksheet
Set sheet = book.Worksheets(IO)
```

If *that* blows up, then the `Worksheets` collection doesn't contain any sheet named after whatever it is that this `IO` variable contains.

Now, all the above is assuming that we're looking for *some sheet* that's in *some workbook*.

> Yes. The sheet is in ThisWorkbook. It's the only Excel document that is open during the macro.

Scrap everything above as superfluous and non-applicable then. All you need is to name the worksheet module in the VBA project. Find the sheet you want in the VBE's *Project Explorer* (Ctrl+R), then find its `(Name)` property (F4). Set the `(Name)` property (note: that is the `(Name)` property, not the `Name` property) to a valid VBA identifier, like `IOSheet`. Now you can use this identifier everywhere in your project, whenever you need to access this specific worksheet.

Once you have a `Worksheet` object, you can get a `Range`:

```
Dim cell As Range
Set cell = IOSheet.Range("A1")
```

That can't blow up in any way, and will work reliably on every computer that runs this code. But `MsgBox cell.Value` could - not with error 9, but if cell `A1` contains a worksheet error, coercing the `Variant/Error` value into a `String` to pass it as the `Prompt` parameter of the `MsgBox` function *will* throw a *type mismatch* error.

So if we want to *safely* display the `Value` of cell `A1` in a message box, we need to be sure it's not a `Variant/Error` first - if it's an error value, we should display the `Text` of the cell, because its `Value` is a variant subtype that can't be coerced into a `String`:

```
If Not IsError(cell.Value) Then
    MsgBox cell.Value
Else
    MsgBox cell.Text
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that the problem user has turned off "hide extensions for known file types" in Windows Explorer - when you do that, `Workbooks(fileName)` requires the file name to include the extension.

So the safest approach is to always include the extension (since that always works, regardless of the extensions setting).

[Windows().Activate works on every computer except one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38745818/windows-activate-works-on-every-computer-except-one/38748754#38748754)