# "Run-Time Error '9'" Subscript Out of Range" after Windows update

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet which was working perfectly until yesterday! For some reason today I updated (KB4601319 and KB4601050) today, and it started showing this message: `Run-Time Error '9' Subscript Out of Range` whenever I try to run my macro.

The command line where the macros gives error is the following:

```
qt120 = objWorkbook.Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs( _
Columns(6), Columns(3), _
"<=" & Workbooks("Leilao 15-04-2020").Worksheets("Arquivos").Cells(4, 13).Text, _
Columns(3), _
">=" & Workbooks("Leilao 15-04-2020").Worksheets("Arquivos").Cells(4, 14).Text)
```

`qt120` is double
`Columns(6)` is double
`Columns(3)` have `hh:mm:ss` format
`Cells (4, 13)` and `Cells (4, 14)` also has `hh:mm` format

I wonder why this formula would stop working all the suddenly!

Comment: Try adding the file extension to the workbook name.

Comment: Add the whole code if you can.

Comment: Is the "Leilao 15-04-2020" file being opened by the macro elsewhere? If so then you don't need to dereference it from the `Workbooks` collection.

Comment: Similar? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59329356/simple-vba-macro-will-work-on-all-computers-except-one/59330511#59330511

Comment: It is the active workbook!

Comment: I use this line before:

 Set objWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(NomeArquivo, ReadOnly:=True, Local:=True)

Where NomeArquivo has the whole path and file extension!

Funny thing though is that I ran the macro on another computer without today's windows updates and it worked fine!

Comment: Let me explain. "Leilao 15-04-2020" is the xlsm file where the macro is, the objWorkbook is a .csv file where I get the data from, and check against the references in "Leilao 15-04-2020".

Comment: As I said what is really funny is that the macro was working fine until yesterday before the windows update. Also, since today it stopped working, I ran it on another computer without the update and it also worked fine! So I wonder how would a windows update cause enough trouble for me not to be able to run the macro anymore? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Ok guys, adding the file extension in "Leilao 15-04-2020" worked! basically changing to "Leilao 15-04-2020.xlsm". I wonder why it stoped working the way it was whan I updated windows.