# Use input box to reference another workbook into sub

Tags: excel, vba

I put together a sub that allows you to input the name of the file you want your sub to refer to instead of encoding a single file.  However beyond the input box, I get the error "subscript out of range".  I tried entering the file name with and without "" and file extension .xls

```
Sub tester()

Dim wbName As String
wbName = Application.InputBox("What is the workbook name?")
If Right(wbName, 4) <> ".xls" Then wbName = wbName + ".xls"
Set mainWB = Workbooks(wbName)

Dim copyThis As Range, pasteThis As Range

Set copyThis = mainWB.Worksheets(2).Columns("F")
Set pasteThis = Workbooks("VBA Workbook.xlsm").Worksheeets(1).Columns("A")

copyThis.Copy Destination:=pasteThis

End Sub
```

Comment: In general including the extension should always work. Not including the extension will *not* work if the user has the Windows Explorer option "hide extensions for know file types" unchecked. What if the user enters "test.xlsx" though ?  your code will change that to "test.xlsx.xls".

Comment: are you saying the code you posted doesn't work? Or you have some other code that is doing this but putting in some string variable in place of the `"VBA Workbook.xlsm"` name you have hard-coded here?

Comment: @TimWilliams Could you expand on the Windows Explorer option?  I am entering the file name ("filename")  the extension is added on and the file is open, however it still returns that it is out of range.

Comment: Previously: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38745818/windows-activate-works-on-every-computer-except-one/38748754#38748754.  See also: https://www.howtogeek.com/205086/beginner-how-to-make-windows-show-file-extensions/   Try changing your code to accept the full filename (including the extension) - does it work?  Also make sure all your workbooks are open in the same instance of Excel: if the selected workbook is open in a different instance of Excel from where your code is running, it's not going to be in the Workbooks collection.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever there is user intervention, you will have to use lot of error handling to avoid possible errors. I recommned using a `Userform` insetad. Instead of the making a user, type the workbook name, use a `UserForm` witm a `ComboBox1` (*As shown in the image below*) populated with the names of all open workbooks so that user can choose the relevant workbook rather than typing the name

[image]

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim wkb As Workbook
    Me.Label1.Caption = "Please select the relevant workbook"
    With Me.ComboBox1
        '~~> Loop thorugh all open workbooks and add
        '~~> their name to the Combobox
        For Each wkb In Application.Workbooks
            .AddItem wkb.Name
        Next wkb
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    If ComboBox1.ListIndex = -1 Then
        MsgBox "Please select a wotkbook name and try again"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim wb As Workbook

    Set wb = Workbooks(ComboBox1.List(ComboBox1.ListIndex))

    With wb
        MsgBox .FullName

        '~~> Do what you want
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks this is interesting.  However I am getting the error "invalid use of me keyword"

Comment: Did you create a Userform and place your control there? `Me` refers to `Userform`

Comment: I added a userform combo box and assigned it to the macro, however it is still returning the invalid use

Comment: You should be getting that but feel free to delete `Me.` It should still work. BTW all this code goes inside the userform.

Comment: It is inside a module I believe as a private sub - how can I place it inside a userform?

Comment: Double click the userform and then paste the code that I gave above :)

Comment: Double click on the userform itself or in the VBE? Ps. I am new to VBA :)

Comment: on the userform design

Comment: Nothing appears to happen when clicking here https://i.stack.imgur.com/kU2WA.png

Comment: Ahh I see.  Thanks!

Comment: Now the question is. 1) Why are there two private subs, and do they work as separate subs? 2) How can I incorporate this in my original script to use the selected workbook as the reference

Comment: `UserForm_Initialize()` populates the combobox when the form is launched. `Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()` is when the user clicks on the commandbutton

Comment: You need to call the userfrom in `Sub tester()` instead of `wbName = Application.InputBox("What is the workbook name?")` By saying `Userform1.show` and then getting the file name in a variable from the combobox or you can copy the code from the sub tester and place it inside the command button

Comment: Okay, got it. So I 1) inserted a combo box user form inside the VBE 2) Double clicking brings me to the code editor.  It is called ````combobox2_change````

Comment: This is what it looks like so far: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aaQxm.png

Comment: I think you need to spend sometime to understand how userform works :) You can try these links **[1]** https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/userform.html **[2]** https://powerspreadsheets.com/create-excel-userforms/ **[3.]** https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-user-forms-1/

Comment: I've successfully got the code to work - thank you!  Now between the ```` with wb ```` and ```` end with ```` should be the script I would like to run with the workbook the user chooses correct?

Comment: Yup @patriciajlim :)

Comment: Thanks.  Now for the next challenge with errors - haha  I have expressed in a separate post. I`m learning!