# Transfer data from one Workbook to another without needing to know the name

Tags: excel, vba

I'm very new to working with VBA.

I am trying to create a macro that allows the user to press a button that allows you to select any Excel workbook, regardless of name, and put the data at the bottom of a master list on the next blank cell. I've pasted the code that I currently have on VBA. Each time that I try to run the code, I get the Run-time error '9' for Subscript out of range.

```
Sub selectFile()

'Create and set dialog box as variable
Dim dialogBox As FileDialog
Set dialogBox = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)

'Do not allow multiple files to be selected
dialogBox.AllowMultiSelect = False

'Set the title of the DialogBox
dialogBox.Title = "Select a file"

'Set the default folder to open
dialogBox.InitialFileName = "C:\Users\ExcelDataFolder"

'Clear the dialog box filters
dialogBox.Filters.Clear
'Apply file filters - use ; to separate filters for the same name
dialogBox.Filters.Add "Excel workbooks", "*.xlsx;*.xls;*.xlsm"


'Show the dialog box and output full file name
If dialogBox.Show = -1 Then
    'ActiveSheet.Range("filePath").Value = dialogBox.SelectedItems(1)
    
    Dim strVar As String
    strVar = Right$(dialogBox.SelectedItems(1), Len(dialogBox.SelectedItems(1)) - InStrRev(dialogBox.SelectedItems(1), "\"))
    
    Dim wsCopy As Worksheet
Dim wsDest As Worksheet
Dim lCopyLastRow As Long
Dim lDestLastRow As Long

  'Set variables for copy and destination sheets
  Set wsCopy = Workbooks(strVar).Worksheets(1)
  Set wsDest = Workbooks("DummyMaster.xlsm").Worksheets(1)
    
  '1. Find last used row in the copy range based on data in column A
  lCopyLastRow = wsCopy.Cells(wsCopy.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
  '2. Find first blank row in the destination range based on data in column A
  'Offset property moves down 1 row
  lDestLastRow = wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row

  '3. Copy & Paste Data
  wsCopy.Range("A2:E" & lCopyLastRow).Copy _
    wsDest.Range("A" & lDestLastRow)
    
End If


    

End Sub
```

Comment: In which line do you get the error?

Comment: You need to open the workbook before `Set wsCopy = Workbooks(strVar).Worksheets(1)` and also, I still don't get what are you doing with `strVar = Right$(dialogBox.SelectedItems(1), Len(dialogBox.SelectedItems(1)) - InStrRev(dialogBox.SelectedItems(1), "\"))` if `SelectedItems(1)` returns the path you want.

Comment: Do you understand that `FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)` **does NOT open the selected files**? It only allows selecting the necessary files and returns their full name. You cannot refer to a workbook name before/without opening it...

Comment: I get the error on - Set wsCopy = Workbooks(strVar).Worksheets(1) @Pᴇʜ

Comment: In addition to opening the workbook, please change ```Set wsDest = Workbooks("DummyMaster.xlsm").Worksheets(1)``` .xlsm is not required when referencing the workbook. This workbook must also be opened.

Comment: @FaneDuru As I had said in the post, I'm completely new to working with VBA, so nearly all of the code was just copy and pasted from other guides while changing certain values that correlate with the files I have.

Comment: That's why I asked? In the VBA world it is known that it does not open the workbook. So, before trying to work with such a workbook **you must open it**. `Dim wb As Workbook` `Set wb = Workbooks.Open(dialogBox.SelectedItems(1))`. Only after that use `Set wsCopy = wb.Worksheets(1)` .Not needed to extract workbook name... It could work as you tried, but **only after opening the workbook selected using `Dialog`**, but why using something not being necessary (anymore)?

Comment: @SergiySavelyev - ".xlsm is not required when referencing the workbook" that is not universally true, and including the file extension is the "safest" approach. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/38748754/478884

Comment: If your code is running in DummyMaster.xlsm then you can use `ThisWorkbook` in place of `Workbooks("DummyMaster.xlsm")`

Comment: @Tim Williams - I personally use ```wbName = ActiveWorkbook.Name
Workbooks(wbName)``` It does not depend on the file explorer settings. Generally, it's not a good practice to hard code the workbook names, as if a user changes it, the code won't work. ThisWorkbook also can be used, but if you need to refence multiple workbooks, then it's easier to store the name in a variable.

Comment: ...or just `Set wb = ActiveWorkbook`?  No need to de-reference using `Name` and later get it back from `Workbooks`

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

```vb
Sub selectFile()

    Dim strVar As String, wbCopy As Workbook, wsCopy As Worksheet
    
    strVar = SelectExcelFile("C:\Users\ExcelDataFolder")
    
    If Len(strVar) = 0 Then Exit Sub 'no file selected
    
    Set wbCopy = Workbooks.Open(strVar)
    Set wsCopy = wbCopy.Worksheets(1)
    
    wsCopy.Range("A2:E" & wsCopy.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Copy _
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        
    wbCopy.Close SaveChanges:=False

End Sub

'ask the user to select an Excel file; optionally set the starting folder
Function SelectExcelFile(Optional startFolder As String = "") As String
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .title = "Select a file"
        If Len(startFolder) > 0 Then .InitialFileName = startFolder
        .Filters.Clear
        .Filters.Add "Excel workbooks", "*.xlsx;*.xls;*.xlsm"
        If .Show = -1 Then SelectExcelFile = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With
End Function
```

Note that keeping your methods short is a good way to keep your code easy to maintain.  One way to do that is to factor out specific tasks (like choosing a file for example) into separate methods.