# Subscript out of range - Can't find Open Workbooks on Another Computer

Tags: excel, vba

I am a newer user of Excel VBA.  I have been checking through all the other questions on here to try to solve my problem.  I created a Master workbook, which copies info from 3 template spreadsheets when I run the macro.  On my computer, it works correctly.  However, when we tried to run it on a coworker's computer with the exact same 4 workbooks open, we ran into the "Subscript out of range" error.

I used the below code from this post ([Out of range error for Windows().Activate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16540071/out-of-range-error-for-windows-activate)) to check the names of all the open workbooks.  Only 1 of the 4 (Master.xlsm) open workbooks displayed when I ran the code on my coworker's computer.  On my computer, it displays 4 out of 4 open workbooks when I run that code

```
dim oBook as workbook

for each obook in workbooks
    debug.print ">" & obook.name & "<"
next
```

Below are the first lines in my code.  It breaks on the first line because it can't find the template workbook even though we have it open.  When we run the above code on my coworker's computer during debugging, the Template1.xlsx workbook is not listed.  I am not sure what is going wrong, and would really appreciate any help on this.

```
Sub Copy_To_Master()

Workbooks("Template1.xlsx").Worksheets("1").Range("A65:E104").Copy
Workbooks("Master.xlsm").Worksheets("1").Range("A65:E104").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

End Sub
```

Comment: Is the template workbook open in protected view on your coworker's computer?

Comment: I don't think so, we saved it to the desktop and opened all the workbooks from there.

Comment: It still could be opened in protected view. That's the only reason I can think of that it would not show up in the `Workbooks` collection.

Comment: OK, I will double-check that and let you know.  I figured it was something like that at first, and looked for the protected view ribbon, but did not see it.  Maybe it is still enabled.

Comment: I tested it on another coworker's computer, the files are not in protected view.  This time it found 3 of the 4 workbooks open.

Comment: NOTE: Don't use underscore `_` in procedure names because those are used to identify Event handlers.

Comment: Thank you, noted, I will remove the underscores from the procedure name.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that your workbooks are opened in different instances. You can't control what your users are going to do so I would recommend opening the files using VBA so that you get a handle on them as they are opened.

```
Dim templateBook as Workbook
Set templateBook = Workbooks.Open("Template1.xlsx")
```

This way you can use the `templateBook` object to do all the things you need to do. I would then further recommend that you keep these workbooks on a server share so their location is reliable. Then any employee can run these things, they all run off the server and you never have to worry about "works on my machine" again.

Finally, don't use copy and paste. Once you have workbook handles you can set values directly without copy and paste. It looks like this:

```
masterBook.Worksheets("1").Range("A65:E104").Value = templateBook.Worksheets("1").Range("A65:E104").Value
```

Comment: _Window objects are like different instances of Excel._ that's just, ... wrong.  Any given instance of Excel  can have many Windows, including  more than 1 per workbook.  That said, the likely cause _is_ that the workbooks are open in different instances of Excel

Comment: That's why I used the word *like* instead of *are*. You can talk to a different instance by using the `Windows` object when you can't access it by using `Workbooks`. That was my point and I believe it holds true.

Comment: Okay, I removed the part about using `Windows` object. The rest of my advice still holds. I looked in to how to attach to other instances of Excel and, you're right, it's much more difficult than using the `Windows` object. I guess I've never actually done it.

Comment: Thank you for this.  I am going to try this out and see if it fixes the weird issues when using the macro on different computers.  Strange thing this morning we tried the macro again on my coworker's computer with the original code, and it worked.

Comment: Yes, it would be intermittent if the problem is how your user opened the workbooks. That's why you shouldn't rely on them when you can automate. Keep it as simple as possible for the user.

Comment: HackSlash, will I need to do Dim masterBook as Workbook also?  I'm just trying to understand the defining variables thing.

Comment: Yes, you should use `Option Explicit` at the top of every module because that forces you to declare all variables with `Dim`. This avoids problems from typos. If you know the variable type you should always declare it as specific as possible. In this case, we know it's a `Workbook`. Doing this will allow intellisense to work. That's the popup that shows what options are available for the object you are working with.

Comment: Thank you! I'm having to read several times and google to understand, but I'm going to try to improve the macro with this.

Comment: I ran into a run-time error '1004' because the template file cannot be found.  Do I need to put the full folder location in?

Comment: Yes, always use the full path because the default path is different on each computer. That's why I told you to put the files on a server share. Then you can hit the same path from all PCs.